# Multiple-select columns converted from 2007 error in 2013 SharePoint Views

Tags: 2013

**Issue** - Choice columns with Allow Multiple, created in 2007 SP have been converted to 2013 SP.  2013 Views that use these columns return the following error
 •Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))

This same result is returned with lists, libraries and datasheet views.

**Workaround** - If we remove these columns the views display as expected.  In addition, you can Edit Properties and see the values on the Task or Document.

**Other details** -
 •User has full-control rights to the site collection and views
•No 3rd-party tools were used in the conversion.  We did a straight back-up/restore and ran PowerShell commands to perform the upgrade to 2010 and then 2013
•We have confirmed that GUID in 2007 SP is the same in 2013 SP for this list item

Please provide any suggestions on how to view 2007 metadata in 2013 SharePoint.